# Should I use "in", “over”, or “within” in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> The boy did his first push up after 10 workouts **in** 20 days.

Should I use "in 20 days", "over 20 days", or "within 20 days"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Over` would be used commonly, but the other two prepositions might be used to emphasize the time span.

> The boy did his first push up after 10 workouts over 20 days.

Connotation: He built up slowly before doing that pushup.

> The boy did his first push up after 10 workouts within 20 days.

Connotation: Impressive! 10 workouts in that time period!